# Azure Terraform log out and back to recognize permissions

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I have a Terraform configuration for an Azure Key Vault:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  # ...
  network_acls {
    default_action = "Deny"
    ip_rules       = ["MY_IP_ADDRESS"]
    bypass         = "AzureServices"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "application" {
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  certificate_permissions = local.permissions_certificates_all
  key_permissions         = local.permissions_keys_all
  secret_permissions      = local.permissions_secrets_all
  storage_permissions     = local.permissions_storage_all
}
```

What happens is that when I attempt to add an `azurerm_key_vault_secret` to the Key Vault that is created above, it fails with the error message:

> Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or application 'appid=ID;oid=ID;iss=https://sts.windows.net/ID/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'KEY_VAULT_NAME;location=eastus2'

When I run the `terraform apply` again, it works just fine.

I tried adding a [time_sleep](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep) with 10 minutes (and a set of [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) needs to ensure it happens) to see if it would resolve it, and it did not.

It seems, however, that the solution is to somehow request that Terraform re-authenticate in some way so that the permissions get picked up.

Is there a way to do this in a Terraform file with the [azurerm provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest) or generically request re-authentication? I did not see it in the documentation.

Thanks!

**Terraform Version Data:**

```
Terraform v1.1.2
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread v2.13.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.90.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.1.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops v0.1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try seeing what happens when you explicitly state the permissions?
In your case as a starting point just get:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "application" {
 key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
 tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
 object_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

 certificate_permissions = local.permissions_certificates_all
 key_permissions         = local.permissions_keys_all
 storage_permissions     = local.permissions_storage_all

 secret_permissions = [
   "Get",
 ]
}
```

Comment: I tried a lot of various combinations and both get and set alone had the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's a timing issue. Terraform applies in parallel threads, so it is trying to add the secret before the policy is added. That is why it works the second time.

To avoid this, you can add a

```
depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.application]
```

to your secret.

This will make the secret creation wait until the policy is added.

Comment: That did not work. I tried that and adding a dependent sleep before any other operations. I'm almost certain this is something where I need to log back in. If I write a script that does this within 1 second that restarts the script it will succeed where even if I wait 5 minutes before other operations it fails.

Comment: @eln00b Were you able to resolve your issue? I'm running into the same problem and created a github issue. Please upvote if you're not able to resolve this yet.https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/17015